# JSF Database connection Managedbean or POJO

Tags: java, database, jsf, jdbc

I'm working on a small JSF Project where I use a DB.
I'm working with DAO's. I'm not sure if I did it right because I never used JSF before.

My DAO's are Managedbeans with the Annotation `@RequestScoped`
My DB connector is a POJO.

My Question is, can my DB connector be a POJO or does it Need to be a Managedbean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a connection service class like follows: (this example assumes you already have a datasource setup in your application server)

```
public class ConnectionDB {

    private Context initContext;

    private static Context webContext;

    private static DataSource dataSource = null;

    private ConnectionDB() {
        try {
            initContext = new InitialContext();

            webContext = (Context) initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env");

            dataSource = (DataSource) webContext.lookup("name_ds");
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static DataSource getDS() {

        if (dataSource == null) {
            new ConnectionDB();
        }

        return dataSource;

    }

}
```

In your web.xml you would need to add the following:

```
    <resource-ref>

    <res-ref-name>name_ds</res-ref-name>

    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>

    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

Notice that I don't have it as a @ManagedBean.

Then you can use that class to initiate your connection in your other service classes, like follows:

```
public class Test{

    private Connection conn;

    private PreparedStatement prstmt;

    private ResultSet rs;

    public void testMethod() {

try {
            conn = ConnectionDB.getDS().getConnection();

            //create your sql, result sets and prepare statements

 }
catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

}

}
```